# How to uniquely identify device on LAN

Tags: router

I am concerned with uniquely identifying devices on the LAN. This is useful for making sure unauthorized devices did not connect to the network and try to access the router. This is also useful for making sure appropriate permissions are applied (e.g. a category of employees are disallowed to access a certain domaine name).

How can I do that?
I thought about filtering by IP or mac addresses. But some devices (e.g. mobile) go out of the network and an offending device could just spoof their mac, or assign to themselves their IP, I believe.

Could I use a sort of encryption key system, so that the router knows who is talking to them, without fear of spoofing? Is this possible, is there an easier solution?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about unauthorized devices in your network you need proper authentication - port-based on your switches or at minimum on the firewall. MAC or IP addresses can be spoofed easily and are not reliable.

Port-based authentication includes IEEE 802.1X and (vastly improved but more costly) MACsec aka 802.1AE.

Most firewalls have several options for user authentication including local users, LDAP and various single sign-on methods.

Comment: Thanks Zac, that’s useful. I will look into these.

Comment: after some research into your pointers, it seems WPA3 Enterprise (based on 802.1X) is a great way to auhenticate. Now I need to find a router that allows access control (parental controls) based on this type of authentication. Do you have pointers at to what routers has this feature?

Comment: Sorry, hardware recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. Basically, any current, business-grade WAP should support WPA3 Enterprise.